# How to make fadeInLeft effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, animation

Hello guys I want to make fadeInLeft effect for my code, how to achieve this? 
I want to change `fadeIn` effect to `fadeInLeft` or `slideLeft`effect.

```
<div>
                <img class="center-triangle animated slideInUp" src="http://i-marketing.loc/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/triangle-pyramid.png" alt="цели SMM" style="opacity: 1;">
            </div>
            <div class="right-info">
                <img id="caption_1" class="" src="http://i-marketing.loc/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/caption_1.png" alt="Имидж, лояльность, доверие">
                <img id="caption_2" class="" src="http://i-marketing.loc/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/caption_2.png" alt="Работа с негативом, обратная связь с клиентом, работа со СМИ">
                <img id="caption_3" class="" src="http://i-marketing.loc/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/caption_3.png" alt="Стимулирование продаж, охват и узнаваемость">
            </div>
```

With this function I can't perform fadeInLeft effect
`numberOfLines.first.fadeIn('slow');`

```
    var numberOfLines = {
    first: $('#caption_1'),
    second: $('#caption_2'),
    third: $('#caption_3')
}

for (var key in numberOfLines) {
    numberOfLines[key].hide(); //numberOfLines[key] holds the `$('#caption_1')...` elements
}

$('.center-triangle').css({ 'position' : 'relative', 'left' : '25%' });
$('.center-triangle').click(function () {
    $(this).animate({
    'left' : '50px'
    }, 500, 'linear',
        function () {
            numberOfLines.first.fadeIn('slow');
            numberOfLines.second.fadeIn('slow');
            numberOfLines.third.fadeIn('slow');
        }
    );//end function animate
});
```

Comment: can you show some html or add a snippet

Comment: @MujthabaIbrahim doesn't work!

Comment: @MujthabaIbrahim I've added HTML code!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
          numberOfLines.first.animate({
          opacity: 'show', // animate fadeIn
          width: 'show'  // animate slideDown
          }, 'slow');
```